# Inconsistent HashMap between classes - Java

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

I have class A which has a HashMap as a public field:

```
public static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And in class B (which is multi-threaded, implements Runnable), I do some puts.

Now, in class C I'm tryin to read from the map. But the changes to the map are not reflected in class C.

I am not storing any references anywhere, but I access the map through the class name.

```
A.map.put("hi", "hello");     //in thread B
A.map.get("hi");              //in thread C
```

And I am sure that I call get() after I call put()..

I thought there could be a problem with concurrency and I changed the HashMap to a Hashtable but it is still the same..

I replicated the problem with as little code as possible

```
public class A {
    public static final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        while(true);
    }
}

public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            String s = sc.nextLine();
            A.map.put(s, "true");
            System.out.println(A.map.size());
        }
    }
}

public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(A.map.size());
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the size increasing in the print in class B, but in C size is always zero..

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What makes you sure you are calling `get()` after `put()`? This really does sound like a race condition (you are calling `get()` first).

Comment: It's not a race condition because the get() and put() are executed on user input. And I print the size after I do a put(). Size increases correctly, but when I print the size in the other class it is always 0.

Comment: If it really isn't a race condition, then I would guess that somehow you are not actually accessing the same map. Could you add more of the relevant code?

Comment: @forgivenson I just edited the question and added an example

Comment: @MinaHany There are 3 main methods. Are you running three Java processes? Processes do not share memory.

Comment: @McDowell Oh gosh, of course! Multiple threads are at the end running in the same process and thus can share memory but this way they will not.. It seems I'm too tired.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

When doing operations from different threads you want to enforce *synchronization* on the **same** object.

Currently, you are not doing any synchronization, so it does not work.

Therefore you have two options:

1. Wrap it into a synchronized map, with `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());`. This enforces synchronization on **all** actions, even if they came form the same thread.
2. Use the same lock for when performing operations on the map. I would not advice the latter method, unless you are going to be doing a lot of operations on a single thread in succession, of whom the other thread needs not to know about.

And as per @Ziker's suggestion, the third option is to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which offers the same thread safety as wrapping it in a `Collections.synchronizedMap`, but does not come at the same costs, meaning this should really be your preferred option.

Comment: or third option `ConcurrentHashMap` It allows concurrent modification of the Map from several threads without the need to block them. Question is if time performance is really important for OP because `synchronizedMap` really increaes time

Comment: @Ziker Good catch there

Comment: If it's different threads, potentially marking the variable `volatile` as well.

Comment: performance isn't an issue, so I switched to ConcurrentHashMap, but it is still the same.. I also tried volatile and it is the same.

Comment: @MinaHany Then what about putting your code (a small part that describes the problem!) in your question?

Comment: Why `A` and `B` do not implement `Runnable` or extend `Thread` class? Can you provide also your main class ?